# Band structure of Group-IV crystals

Tags: semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory, density-functional-theory

Talking specifically about the $sp^3$ hybridized crystals, it can be seen that all the group-IV elements from carbon to germanium sport a band gap in the bulk of their crystals, but Sn and Pb. Also we see that as we move down the order from Diamond to Lead crystals, the band gap shrinks and the valence band and conduction band overlap on the $\alpha$-Sn phase, giving us metallic behaviors. My question is why is this systematics present or rather, what underlying phenomena causes this behavior? This behavior representing the change gradient talked about is well represented in the band structures shown below (Si-Ge-$\alpha$-Sn from top to bottom).

[image: Si-band_structure]

[image: Ge-band_structure]

[image: alpha-Sn-band_structure]

Comment: Dear editor, after the editing we don't even know which band-structure is from which crystal. It would be difficult for others to read the question properly and will hence push important traffic away from my question leaving it unanswered